# What is the best way to keep track of month ends for deleting rows for a specific resource?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I was making a simple rest api with Flask, Flask-Restful and Flask-sqlAlchemy where I have a user resource and an item resource. User resource is the parent resource of the Item resource.

That is

GET https://example.com/users/1/items
 to get all the item resource

I want to delete all the items after each month automatically. The problem is how to keep track of the month end?

I did some research and found python datetime and calendar library.

Below code is how I can get the month end of the day a user registers and then I can calculate the rest of the start and end date of the months for the year and save it in the database. But now I will have to check datetime.datetime.today() everytime and then check with the start and end date and delete the item resource under a particular user. Is that efficient to check datetime.datetime.today() everytime and if that equals to end date then delete all the item resouces?

This is how I can calculate start and end date

```py
import datetime
import calendar

today = datetime.datetime.today()



days_in_current_month = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]

days_till_this_month_end = days_in_current_month -today.day

start_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days = days_till_this_month_end +1)
end_date = start_date

while some_condition:
    # details of the condision

days_in_current_month = calendar.monthrange(end_date.year, end_date.month)[1]

end_date  = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days = days_till_this_month_end +1)
```

This is my UserModel:

```py
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String())
    items = db.relationship('ItemModel', lazy = "dynamic")
```

This is my ItemModel:

```py
class ItemModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "categories"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = db.relationship('UserModel')
```

and finally to delete the items I can do the below:

```
@staticmethod
def delete_from_db():
    ItemModel.query.filter(start_date <= end_date).delete()
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Your `ItemModel` doesn't have a date column. Without a date column, how will you know that it was created in a specific month?

Comment: I have several other classes to make it simple I have modified my classes in the question and ended up missing the date field. sorry about that. I have edited it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ItemModel` query filter doesn't specify any columns; the `start_date <= end_date` expression is always `True` (as the `end_date` value is always going to be later in time than your `start_date`). You are also over-complicating matters.

All you have to do is delete all rows *before* the start of the current month. The database will take it from there. The start of the current month is trivially determined with:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
month_start = today.replace(day=1)  # set day of the month to 1

ItemModel.query.filter(ItemModel.date < month_start).delete()
```

Running this on each query is cheap enough, especially if the `ItemModel.date` column is indexed.

If you are targeting a specific database, then you could also use the database's date functions. Postgresql, for example, has a handy [`date_trunc()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) that can be used to specify what rows to drop:

```
ItemModel.query.filter(
    ItemModel.date < func.date_trunc('month', func.current_date())
).delete()
```

This uses the [PostgreSQL `CURRENT_DATE` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), truncates it down to the current month (which sets the day of the date to 1), then removes all rows that precede the current month.

If you feel these delete queries are too costly to run on every single request, consider creating a [*table view*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) of the `items` table, and use that view in your SQLAlchemy model. The view query then only shows items from the current month:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE current_items WITH
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE items.date >= date_trunc(CURRENT_DATE, 'month')
```

and use `current_items` as the table name to back your `ItemModel` objects, and have a separate batch process drop any rows from the items table that are older, to keep the database clean. That way your SQLAlchemy queries only ever get to see items from the current month, and deletion is done once every while the batch process gets round to deleting those rows.

Instead of a view, you could also have SQLAlchemy apply the filter automatically, via event hooks. This is a [filtered query implementation](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/FilteredQuery):

```
@event.listens_for(Query, "before_compile", retval=True)
def before_itemmodel_compile(query):
    """Limit all ItemModel queries to the current month"""
    if query._execution_options.get("include_all", False):
        return query

    for ent in query.column_descriptions:
        entity = ent['entity']
        if entity is None:
            continue
        insp = inspect(ent['entity'])
        mapper = getattr(insp, 'mapper', None)
        if mapper and mapper.class_ is ItemModel:
            today = datetime.date.today()
            month_start = today.replace(day=1)  # set day of the month to 1
            query = query.enable_assertions(False).filter(
                ent['entity'].date >= month_start)

    return query
```

Comment: But Do I have to continuously check the current date everytime? Isn't going to effect the latency?

Comment: @Reactive_learner: not really. Getting the current date is very cheap. Sending a delete query out to the database server can be 'slow' in that it takes time to send the query over the network certainly takes a bit of time (in the milliseconds range, depending on how far removed the database server is), but since a DELETE query doesn't produce rows, that time is negligible compared to SELECT queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing I wanted to ask you is should I use it like a schedule task? Because It will be executed without any request

Comment: @Reactive_learner: if you are batch-deleting items recorded in a previous month, then yes, that'd be a schedule task.

Comment: Yes that's exact what I want to do.

Comment: I ended up using apscheduler package, it is working in my test. I have added the code in the question for you. Is it a bad way of doing this?

Comment: @Reactive_learner: sorry, the Flask-Resource comment got misdirected, that one was meant for another post (not sure how I got the wires crossed)

Comment: @Reactive_learner: I rolled back your change; how to run periodic tasks isn't really part of this question, that's a new discussion, altogether. How to best do periodic tasks depends heavily on how you are deploying your app, anyway. Cron jobs, platform-specific schedulers, or apscheduler all have their pros and cons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192587/discussion-between-reactive-learner-and-martijn-pieters).